# Check the manual that corresponds to MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.tcet@gmail.com' at line 1"

Tags: php

Here I am trying to create separate database with the name of each and every email id that have been entered. I want the database name to be the email id entered by the user.

**Error:**

> check the manual that corresponds to MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '.tcet@gmail.com' at line 1"

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die($conn->connect_error);
} 

$email = $conn->query("SELECT username FROM `register` ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1");
$result = $email->fetch_assoc();
$final = $result['username'];

$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $final";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Here, in the above code, I am fetching the entered email id by the user and trying to create a database by the name of same email id that has been fetched. But I am getting the above error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''miths.tcet@gmail.com'' at line 1. It now shows this error. KIKO Software

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention. The name of a database has to obey certain rules. See: [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html). So the dots and the `@` are not allowed.

Comment: Can I just say that it is _highly unusual_ to create a database for every user? You probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database names with `.` and `@` are legal in MariaDB (but should be avoided nonetheless, as they're difficult to treat). With your first SQL query you already used the ` character (enclosing the table name) but don't seem to have understood its purporse. Long story short:

```
CREATE DATABASE a.b@c
```

won't work, but

```
CREATE DATABASE `a.b@c`
```

will.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-names/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_backticks